# Magento 2.3 validate form instant

Tags: magento2.3, validation, form-validation

I want to validate the form on our Magento 2.3 store instant.
So when a value is added into the input field, it should validate this instant and add some css class or id to the input field.

In that case we can add a validation check to the input, so the customer knows that the input is right.

This is quite easy for M1, but I can not find a solution for M2.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: Use onkey up event and validate using jquery

Comment: @BhavinShah Thanks! Any idea how to achieve this?